# Position leaflet map in flex column and make it fill whole container

Tags: css, flexbox, leaflet, chakra-ui

I have something like this:

- [image]
- [image]

These are two different breakpoints. When container is stretched by form, map fills its container, but when flex changes direction to row it does not. How do I fix this without giving fixed value for map height?

I am using Chakra UI lib but it does not really matter, pure css solution is also fine.

```
<Stack mt="2" direction={{ base: 'column', md: 'row' }}>
          <Box
            flex={{ md: 1, sm: 1, lg: 2 }}
            bg="white"
            p="2"
            shadow="sm"
            borderRadius="4"
          >
            <CreateDeviceMap
              zoom={10}
              style={{ height: '100%' }}
              center={[51.472829664858644, -0.06935119628906251]}
            />
          </Box>
          <Stack
            flex="1"
            bg="white"
            shadow="sm"
            p="4"
            spacing="2"
            borderRadius="4"
          >
           ... form
          </Stack>
</Stack>
```

UPDATE:

If I put height:100vh to container map shows and it is fine on small breakpoint but it destroys bigger breakpoints, they become streched. So  I just need to find sweet spot between them.

Comment: Did you try using `flex-wrap:wrap` on the parent container ?

Comment: There is no change with wrap